# Are Erlang funs garbage collected?

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang

If one generates `funs` in erlang, are they garbage collected? For instance to replicate a python like `iterator` or to read a stream, one may generate `fun`s for every yield -- potentially a great many. The used `fun`s are no longer required after use, so are they eventually garbage collected?

I guess that is to say, is such an object as `#Fun<erl_eval.xx.yyyyyyy>` an atom?

Comment: Perhaps a specific case of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383248/are-erlang-references-garbage-collected) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I guess that is to say, is such an object as #Fun<erl_eval.xx.yyyyyyy>
> an atom?

No, a fun is not an atom, rather a fun is its own data type.  At some point, you will see the following ordering of erlang's data types in the docs:

```
number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < map < nil < list < bit string
```

which means you can write things like this:

```
1> 12 < fun(X) -> X end. 
true

2> abc < fun(X) -> X end.
true

3> [1, 2, 3] < fun(X) -> X end.
false
```

Comment: Of course! ...and The number of times I've seen that type ordering. Thanks!